# Firebase for iOS app is not working as expected

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I have been having this issue where I follow all steps to install and run firebase on my app but when I attempt to use it, there is no sign of Firebase working. I create a new profile and even if all the parameters are right, it displays an error. at first I though it was me until I downloaded a working project and tried to create an account on that and it did not connect to firebase. Does anyone here have an idea of what i should do?

note: I followed all steps on firebase's site and I even linked a project but it seems the feature to test connection is no long there.

Completed**** After some struggle i took everyones advice and i instead re-did the project following the same steps. it seems as if i had deleted the pod file at the beginning creating connection issue and it seems to have solved everything. I apologize for the vagueness of everything but being new i wasnt sure how else to explain myself. thank you to everyone who had helped!

Comment: "I followed all steps"  What are those steps?  Which Firebase servie are you referring to?

Comment: so i created my project installed all the proper pod files (made sure they were up to date) copied the proper build id and it doesnt ask to verify it just says to continue. I then put in the proper Auth.auth() method to create an again for email/password but it always returns an error. doesnt even look like its connecting to firebase.

Comment: I don't even get the initialization "logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled " when i launch

Comment: "It displays an error" -- what error? What you have so far is unlikely to be enough information to diagnose the issue.

Comment: You haven't mentioned that you have added GoogleService-Info.plist to the project.

Comment: ah sorry yes i have added google service. the error is from the Auth.auth. when i request { (result, error) its almost like it doesnt even go to firebase it just states there is an error and i get my print statement saying there was an error creating user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jnpdx mentioned in the comments, it is very difficult for others to know what the exact issue is without more information.

However, I'll take a stab in the dark. Since you tried with a working project and it still didn't work, I'd say it's not related to your code. You are probably missing a step that was described in the Firebase Docs. I would re-read them, paying close attention to the authentication section, and hopefully you will find the step you are missing. It could be something as simple as not enabling a certain authentication provider, or forgetting to add the GoogleService-Info.plist file into your project (if you're using Google Sign-in).

Best of luck.

Comment: yeah the wording of my "error" was not accurate. The error i receive is from my Auth.auth in which instead of making a result and sending it to firebase, it just prints the error statement i set. as for the firebase documents. i have done every step multiple times on multiple installs to make sure i wasnt missing a step. would i need to upload my app or is there maybe a setting i might be glossing over? something that any of you may have come across when first working with firebase?

Comment: I mean, you DO have to add the app as a project on Firebase... However, you don't need to upload it to App Store Connect or anything like that. Can you post the description of the error with `error.localizedDescription` and share that?

Comment: There is definitely a step you have missed in the Firebase Docs though, that I'm certain of.